# Summing an array using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array with the size of n which is filled with the numbers 1..n.

I need to sum this array using m threads by each time taking two elements, sum them up and inserting the sum back to the array.

Here is what I tried to do.

The synchronized part first

```
public class MultiThreadedSum {

private ArrayBuffer ArrayBufferInst;
private int Sum;
private boolean Flag;

public MultiThreadedSum(ArrayBuffer ArrayBufferInst)
{
    this.ArrayBufferInst = ArrayBufferInst;
    Sum = 0;
    Flag = false;
}

public synchronized void Sum2Elements()
{

    while(Flag)
    {
        try {wait();}
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }

    Flag = true;

    if (ArrayBufferInst.RetunrSize() < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Removing 2 elements.");

    Sum = ArrayBufferInst.Sum2Elements();

    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void InsertElement()
{

    while(!Flag)
    {
        try {wait();}
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }

    Flag = false;

    System.out.println("Inserting the sum.");

    ArrayBufferInst.InsertElement(Sum);

    notifyAll();
}

public int RetunrSize()
{
    return ArrayBufferInst.RetunrSize();
}

}
```

I've splitted the m threads to 2 groups, half of them will do the summarization and half will do the adding using wait and notify.

```
public class Sum2ElementsThread implements Runnable{

    private MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst;    

    public Sum2ElementsThread( MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst)
    {
        this.MultiThreadedSumInst = MultiThreadedSumInst;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(MultiThreadedSumInst.RetunrSize() > 1)
        {
            MultiThreadedSumInst.Sum2Elements();
        }

    }

}

public class InsertThread implements Runnable{

    private MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst;    

    public InsertThread( MultiThreadedSum MultiThreadedSumInst)
    {
        this.MultiThreadedSumInst = MultiThreadedSumInst;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(MultiThreadedSumInst.RetunrSize() > 1)
        {
            MultiThreadedSumInst.InsertElement();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is part of the main:

```
ArrayBufferInst = new ArrayBuffer(n);

MultiThreadedSumInst = new MultiThreadedSum(ArrayBufferInst);

ExecutorService Threads = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

for (i = 0; i < m/2; i++)
{
    Threads.execute( new Sum2ElementsThread(MultiThreadedSumInst) );
}

for (; i < m; i++)
{
    Threads.execute( new InsertThread(MultiThreadedSumInst) );
}

while (MultiThreadedSumInst.RetunrSize() > 1){}

Threads.shutdown();
```

And the buffer

```
public class ArrayBuffer {

    private ArrayList<Integer> ArrayBufferInst;

    public ArrayBuffer(int SizeOfBuffer)
    {
        int i;

        ArrayBufferInst = new ArrayList<>(SizeOfBuffer);

        for (i = 0; i < SizeOfBuffer; i++)
        {
            ArrayBufferInst.add(i, i+1);
        }
    }

    public int Sum2Elements()
    {
        if (ArrayBufferInst.size() < 2)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return ArrayBufferInst.remove(0) + ArrayBufferInst.remove(1);
    }

    public void InsertElement(int Elem)
    {
        ArrayBufferInst.add(Elem);
    }

    public int RetunrSize()
    {
        return ArrayBufferInst.size();
    }
}
```

I'm getting a lot of java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException and RangeCheck errors, it may be something to do with the way I implemented Sum2Elements but I'm not sure.

Any help guys?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to sum them two at a time and then keep re-adding the sums to the array? The general method to do this is to instead break the input array into m chunks and have each thread sum up its own independent chunk, and then merge those results down into one (often using a hypercube order - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube).

Comment: I wonder if perhaps this method of using a thread to add two numbers at a time is not actually slower?

Comment: The whole point of using multiple threads is to make the code run faster.  I would make sure this is faster than a simple single threaded loop.  If not, it's a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Well, it's kind of an assignment... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this is called on the ArrayList `{a, b, c}`

```
    if (ArrayBufferInst.size() < 2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return ArrayBufferInst.remove(0) + ArrayBufferInst.remove(1);
```

Then `ArrayBufferInst.remove(0)` will remove and return `a`, changing `ArrayBufferInst` to `{b, c}`. Calling `ArrayBufferInst.remove(1)` will then remove **c**, which is not what you want. So just change the 1 to a 0.